# Text block not Updated

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I added one text block and bind the first item of array to that text block. I called some API to get the data for that array. But the text block will not be updated when adding values to that array. When calling API it takes some time to get the data, at that time the Text block is rendered. So, After the text block rendered the UI is not updated.

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemSource[0], UpdateSourceTrigger 
=PropertyChanged}" />
```

View Model:

```
await this.MyMethod();
this.ItemSource[0] = "Test  After";
```

Comment: `this.ItemSource[0] = "Test  After";` does not fire any kind of change notification that would trigger the Binding. Besides that, setting `Mode=TwoWay` makes no sense for the Text property of a TextBlock, and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has no effect on a OneWay Binding.

Comment: @Clemens then what is the way to update that text block when adding items to that array?

Comment: Populate the array with instances of a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. E.g. create an appropriate StringWrapper class. Then bind like `Text="{Binding Path=ItemSource[0].Value}"` and update the Value property by `this.ItemSource[0].Value = "Test  After";`

Comment: Besides that, it's unclear why you have such a Binding to an array element at all. It's kind of unusual.

Comment: @Clemens I am having 20 text blocks in one page. Instead of creating 20 properties, I creating a string array and assign that values to that text blocks.

Comment: Like Clemens said, the approach is strange. What type of array is the ItemSource? Is it a List<String> or an ObservableCollection<String>?

Comment: @LupuSilviu It's obviously a `string[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to bind a number of TextBlocks to a modifiable collection of strings, you could easily use an ItemsControl with a view model like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<string>(
            Enumerable
                .Range(1, 20)
                .Select(i => i.ToString())); // or any other initial values
}
```

The MainWindow constructor

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

In XAML use an ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now something like

```
((ViewModel)DataContext).Items[0] = "Hello";
```

would replace the first string in the collection and hence update the ItemsControl.